# Ubuntu-latest GitHub runner cannot Connect to localhost API

Tags: ubuntu, python, python3, github, api

What specifically needs to be changed in the below in order for a program running on an `Ubuntu-latest` GitHub runner to successfully connect to a Twisted web server running on `localhost` of the same GitHub runner?

The same code works on a Windows laptop, with only minor changes like using `where twistd` on Windows versus `which twistd` on Ubuntu as shown below.

**SOME RELEVANT CODE:**

The code to start the Twisted web server on localhost is in a script called `twistdStartup.py` that reads as follows:

```
import subprocess
import re
import os

escape_chars = re.compile(r'\x1B\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]')

def runShellCommand(commandToRun, numLines=999):
  proc = subprocess.Popen( commandToRun,cwd=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
  while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if line:
      if numLines == 1:
        return escape_chars.sub('', line.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\r|\n'))
      else:
        print(escape_chars.sub('', line.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\r|\n')))
    else:
      break

print("About to create venv.")
runShellCommand("python3 -m venv venv")

print("About to activate venv.")
runShellCommand("source venv/bin/activate")

print("About to install flask.")
runShellCommand("pip install Flask")
print("About to install requests.")
runShellCommand("pip install requests")
print("About to install twisted.")
runShellCommand("pip install Twisted")

##Set environ variable for the API
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = '.'
print("Done updating PYTHONPATH.  About to start server.")

twistdLocation = runShellCommand("which twistd", 1)
startTwistdCommand = twistdLocation+" web --wsgi myAPI.app  &>/dev/null & "
print("startTwistdCommand is: ", startTwistdCommand)

subprocess.call(startTwistdCommand, shell=True)
print("startTwistdCommand should be running in the background now.")
```

The code in a calling program named `startTheAPI.py` that invokes the above `twistdStartup.py` is:

```
myScript = 'twistdStartup.py'
print("About to start Twisted.")
subprocess.Popen(["python", myScript], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print("Just finished starting Twisted.")
```

The logs produced by that step in the GitHub Action job are as follows:

```
About to start Twisted.
Just finished starting Twisted.
```

The results of running the curl command on the same Ubuntu-latest GitHub runner in the next step of the same job after waiting 30 seconds for startup are as follows:

```
$ curl http://localhost:1234/api/endpoint/
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 1234 after 1 ms: Connection refused
```

The contents of a `callTheAPI.py` program that runs the `curl` command would look like:

```
import subprocess
import re
import os

escape_chars = re.compile(r'\x1B\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]')

def runShellCommand(commandToRun, numLines=999):
  proc = subprocess.Popen( commandToRun,cwd=None, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
  while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if line:
      if numLines == 1:
        return escape_chars.sub('', line.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\r|\n'))
      else:
        print(escape_chars.sub('', line.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\r|\n')))
    else:
      break

print("About to call API.")    
runShellCommand("curl http://localhost:1234/api/endpoint/")
print("Done calling API.")
```

**SUMMARY:**

The `twistdStartup.py` script is running, but is failing to provide any output to the logs despite all the `print()` commands.  The curl command fails to connect to the correctly-stated `http://localhost:1234/api/endpoint/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding:

> The curl command fails to connect to the correctly-stated http://localhost:1234/api/endpoint/

The main problem here is that every command you run with `runShellCommand("somecommand")` is executed in a new shell so all changes such as functions,variables, environment variables, etc. disappear after the commands is executed.

For example, try running this simple script in your `twistdStartup.py`:

```py
print("Running echo $PATH")
runShellCommand("echo $PATH")

print("Running PATH=/")
runShellCommand("PATH=/")

print("Running echo $PATH")
runShellCommand("echo $PATH")
```

The output (in my case):

```
Running echo $PATH
/home/edgar/.local/bin:/home/edgar/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
Running PATH=/
Running echo $PATH
/home/edgar/.local/bin:/home/edgar/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

As you can see above the assignment `Running PATH=/` is *ignored* when I run again `runShellCommand("echo $PATH")`.

The *possible* solution (untested with all your commands) here is that you wrap all your `runShellCommand` method calls in a single method call (or convert the code to a shell script), like this:

**Section twistdStartup.py:**

```py
runShellCommand(
"""
set -e
echo About to create venv.
python3 -m venv venv

echo About to activate venv.
. venv/bin/activate

echo About to install flask.
pip install Flask

echo About to install requests.
pip install requests

echo About to install twisted.
pip install Twisted

export PYTHONPATH='.'
echo Done updating PYTHONPATH.  About to start server.

twistdLocation=$(which twistd)

echo "Running ${twistdLocation} web --wsgi customControllerAPI.app  &>/dev/null &"

( 
$twistdLocation web --wsgi myAPI.py  >/dev/null 2>&1
)&


echo startTwistdCommand should be running in the background now.
""")
```

Testing on GitHub Actions I noticed that `source venv/bin/activate`  caused a fail because `source` was not valid (possibly the default shell for Ubuntu in GitHub is `dash`).
Instead of using `source` instead you have to use `.` (which is far better): `. venv/bin/activate`.
Because of the error above the command: `which twistd` was not working  correctly because the **venv** was not sourced. Thus the command:
`$twistdLocation web --wsgi customControllerAPI.app  &>/dev/null` will fail and the Flask API will never run (for that reason you get the messahe: `Failed to connect to localhost port 1234 after 1 ms: Connection refused`)

Regarding:

> but is failing to provide any output to the logs despite all the print() commands

By looking your [file `api_server.py`](https://github.com/jtravell/localhost-api/blob/main/code/api_server.py) I see you are calling the python script `setup.py`:

> `apiServer = subprocess.Popen(["python", "setup.py"], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, cwd=str(path))`

Here you are not getting the output the command `python setup.py`, so I suggest you remove that line and add these ones:

```py
    apiServer = subprocess.Popen(["python", "setup.py"], cwd=str(path),stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    while True:
        line = apiServer.stdout.readline()

        if line:
            print(self.escape_chars.sub('', line.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\r|\n')))
        else:
          break
```

---

1. You may want to change the line `twistdLocation=$(which twistd)` to `twistdLocation=$(command -v twistd)`. See [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/414186)
2. Also I suggest you add the line `set -e` in the first line of the script. That command is used to abort the execution of the following commands if some error has been thrown (so in your case if some dependencies fails to install itself then the scripts stops).
3. About `($twistdLocation web --wsgi myAPI.py  >/dev/null 2>&1 )&` I used that in order to prevent to the python `subprocess` from waiting to read output from that command since this one was causing to the server a "infinity" stuck).
4. If you are interested in the logs (`stdout` and `stderr`) of the command: `$twistdLocation ...` you should redirect the output to a file, like this:

```bash
( 
$twistdLocationn web --wsgi myAPI.py  >/tmp/twistd.logs 2>&1
)&
```

Also you will have to edit your github action to include the command which `cat` the content of `/tmp/twistd.logs`, like this:

```yml
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v3
  - shell: bash
    name: Start the localhost Server
    run: |
      echo "Current working directory is: "
      echo "$PWD"
      python code/commandStartServer.py
      echo "Checking twistd logs"
      cat /tmp/twistd.logs
```

---

So in these files you have to have the following code:

**api_server.py**

```py
import os
import re
 
class api_server:
  
  def __init__(self):  
    pass

  escape_chars = re.compile(r'\x1B\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]')
 
  def startServer(self):
    path = os.getcwd()+"/api/"
    print(path)
    print("About to start .")
    import subprocess
    #The version of command on next line runs the server in the background.  Comment it out and replace with the one below it if you want to see output.
    apiServer = subprocess.Popen(["python", "setup.py"], cwd=str(path),stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    while True:
        line = apiServer.stdout.readline()

        if line:
            print(self.escape_chars.sub('', line.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\r|\n')))
        else:
          break

    #The second version of the command below will print output to the console, but will also halt your program because it runs the server in the foreground.
    #apiServer = subprocess.Popen(["python", "setup.py"], cwd=str(path))
    print("Just finished starting .")

  def destroyServer(self):
    ... # your current code
```

**setup.py**

```py
import subprocess
import re
import os

escape_chars = re.compile(r'\x1B\[[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]')

def runShellCommand(commandToRun, numLines=999):
  proc = subprocess.Popen( commandToRun,cwd=None,  shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if line:
      if numLines == 1:
        return escape_chars.sub('', line.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\r|\n'))
      else:
        print(escape_chars.sub('', line.decode('utf-8').rstrip('\r|\n')))
    else:
      break

runShellCommand(
"""
set -e
echo About to create venv.
python3 -m venv venv

echo About to activate venv.
. venv/bin/activate

echo About to install flask.
pip install Flask

echo About to install requests.
pip install requests

echo About to install twisted.
pip install Twisted

export PYTHONPATH='.'
echo Done updating PYTHONPATH: $PYTHONPATH.  About to start server.

twistdLocation=$(which twistd)

echo "Running ${twistdLocation} web --wsgi customControllerAPI.app  &>/dev/null &"

( 
$twistdLocation web --wsgi myAPI.py  >/dev/null 2>&1
)&


echo startTwistdCommand should be running in the background now.
""")
```

**localhost-api.yml**

```yml
name: localhost-api
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  start-and-then-call-localhost-api:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - shell: bash
        name: Start the localhost Server
        run: |
          echo "Current working directory is: "
          echo "$PWD"
          python code/commandStartServer.py
          echo "Checking twistd logs"
          cat /tmp/twistd.logs
      - shell: bash
        name: Call the localhost API
        run: |
          echo "Current working directory is: "
          echo "$PWD"
          python code/commandCallAPI.py
      - shell: bash
        name: Destroy the localhost Server
        run: |
          echo "Current working directory is: "
          echo "$PWD"
          python code/commandDestroyServer.py
```

Comment: @CodeMed I'm not sure why you it didn't work for you. Maybe you can do something similar to `runShellCommand`. In the line `subprocess.Popen(["python", myScript])` assign the output to a variable `proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", myScript])` and read its content (maybe you have to add again the parameters: `stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`)

Comment: @CodeMed No problem! I'll try to give a check to all the code. I've never worked with `GitHub Actions` but I don't think I have to learn it (but if it's necessary at all then I would try to learn it). I'll try your code and check if the API does run correctly. I'm not sure why you don't get the any output by using the code I provided, in my case it does work. But, by the way, the suggestion about wrap all commands of such method `runShellCommand("command")` must be considered , since you are using a `virtualenv` and `sourcing` a script then  running several `runShellCommand` will never work.

Comment: @CodeMed ok, I will keep it in mind.  Regarding `show a link to a minimal GitHub repository that uses a modified/corrected version of the above code to resolve this problem.` I think it'd be hard to found a repository which has that solution. Or do you want the solution provided to your question points to a GitHub repository (in my github repository in case I provide a solution)?

Comment: @CodeMed Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142686/discussion-between-edgar-magallon-and-codemed).

Comment: Thank you and +525 for resolving this problem.

Comment: @CodeMed you're welcome! And glad to know this has been solved :). This was also useful for me since I learned to use GitHub Actions, they are useful